# Al hacer cambio de ramas trae las modificaciones de la rama origen

Tags: git, github

Buenas, tengo un problema al intentar cambiar de rama ya que cuando realizo el cambio en vez de darme el mensaje

> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.

me deja cambiar de rama y además me trae los cambios de esa rama el flujo que estoy realizando es el siguiente:

> **1 - git checkout -b new_branch**
>
> **2- Modifico algún archivo en el new_branch**
>
> **3- git checkout origin_branch**

Dejo una imagen más explicativa, de antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

[image: Error flujo de git]

Mi pregunta es por que los cambios realizados en distintas ramas se transfieren entre las ramas al hacer checkout ?  El comportamiento que necesito es el que sucede por ejemplo si intento hacer checkout desde la rama develop a la rama master :

[image: flujo corecto]

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el tema de  'git stash' creo que esto es lo que necesitas. Mira esto: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Las-herramientas-de-Git-Guardado-r%C3%A1pido-provisional

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me funcionó, tengo una pregunta por qué desde la rama develop a master me pide que realice un commit y desde otras ramas no ?

Comment: Si te pide un commit es porque git detecta cambios en la rama que estas abandonando. Dependiendo del sistema operativo o del editor que utilices es posible que se produzcan cambios al pasar de rama a rama. Por ejemplo a mi me pasa con WebStorm. Lo ideal es que cierres tu ide antes de cambiar de rama.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @Camilo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es el funcionamiento normal de git, hasta que no haces commit de los cambios éstos no se aislan y permanecen aunque cambies de rama.

Una buena costumbre es limpiar el área de trabajo antes de cambiar. Si algo ha quedado a medias y está en un estado en el que no tiene sentido que lo confirmes, lo mejor es que uses el *guardado rápido provisional*, **"stash"** como te comentan más arriba. Es una especie de "porta papeles"

El flujo de trabajo sería algo así:

Antes de cambiar de rama:

```
# git stash // Esto guarda las modificaciones no confirmadas limpiándolas del área de trabajo
```

Puedes comprobar que ya no están los cambios

```
# git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Luego puedes cambair a otra rama, confirmar otros cambios

```
# git checkout otra-rama  
# git add *
# git commit
```

Volver a la rama master

```
# git checkout master
```

Y recuperar el estado que guardaste sin confirmar:

```
#git stash apply
```

Comment: Otro comando que me ha servido cuando hay archivos en el estado untracked y necesito hacerle stash es el siguiente _git stash save -u_